# Reaction of 1,2-diketones with periodic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, reactivity, organic-oxidation, reagents

$\ce{HIO4}$ can oxidise alcohols. But does $\ce{HIO4}$ undergo any reaction/act as oxidant with 1,2-diketones?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaprade_reaction

Comment: I have just noticed that HIO4 / H5IO6 , even if they are periodic acids, are not periodic acids. :-)

Comment: @Poutnik Be aware that $\ce{NaIO4}$ equally is capable to shrink your cellulose and cotton based bills (well, except in Australia with their polymer AU$).  Strong _et al._, «How To Shrink Paper Money: A Macroscopic Demonstration of the Malaprade Reaction», J. Chem. Educ. 2019, 96, 6, 1199-1204, doi 10.1021/acs.jchemed.8b00951

Comment: @Poutnik I didn't got that joke. Can you explain? :-/

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh periodic(1) = per-iodic versus periodic(2) = regularly repeating :-). E.g. PVC has periodic(2) occurance of Cl atom at every other C atom, even if there is no bound periodic(1) acid. Funny thing was I had originally read the title as periodic(2), partly because in my native language iodine/iodide are jod/jodid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, under basic conditions to give two carboxylic acids, according to this paper by Bunton & Shiner J. Chem. Soc., 1960, 1593-1598  [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1960/JR/jr9600001593#!divAbstract)

Abstract of the paper:

> The oxygen atom of the acetone from oxidation of pinacol and 2-methyl- propane-1,Z-diol by periodic acid comes from the l,Z-diol, in agreement with the suggestion that an intermediate is formed by electrophilic attack of the periodate. In contrast to this, the additional oxygen atom of acetic  acid, formed by oxidation of biacetyl by periodate in basic solution, comes from the periodate. The mechanism is a nucleophilic attack by periodate upon the carbonyl-carbon atom,  and does not seem to involve the hydrates of the ketone as intermediates. In the oxidation of methylacetoin by periodic acid the oxygen of the acetone comes from the hydroxyl group of the hydroxy- ketone, and the additional  oxygen atom of the acetic  acid comes from the periodate. The mechanism  probably  involves  nucleophilic attack by the periodate  ion  upon the carbonyl  group, and co-ordination of the hydroxyl group on to the iodine atom of the periodate.