# Attack of HClO4 to dipropylcycloprop-2-en-1-one

Tags: organic-chemistry

What are the products when $\ce{HClO4}$ attacks this compound?
[image: structure of compound]

I expect $\ce{HClO4}$ to protonate the ketone, forming an (aromatic?) carbocation. I don't know where to go from here.
Answer suggests formation of butanoic acid and production of $\ce{CO2}$. Unsure what really happens here. All hints appreciated.

This question appeared in the JEE 1997.

Comment: That is one very strained system, so once it protonates it is going to rearrange

Comment: @Waylander thanks for your insight - it would be amazing if you could elaborate yourself further; what rearrangement do you see happening? Do you see ring cleavage?

Comment: I wonder where the extra oxygens come from if you are getting butanoic acid and CO2? Presumably the perchloric acid is an aq solution.

Comment: See this prior thread on StackExchange at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31670/reaction-of-perchloric-acid-with-cyclopropenol

Comment: AJKOER, I've already seen that question as well as the accepted answer - but I'm unable to see how anything from there could possibly help me with this question.... :(

@Waylander If we assume that the acid is an aqueous solution, what do you feel may happen? I'm unable to see what potential difference it could make...

Comment: Unfortunately this was exam for high school students required to answer in a limited time. May be this is of the fragmentation reactions grob's fragmentation reaction refer to this in Wikipedia                                     https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grob_fragmentation#Reaction_mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your end products are correct I think this reaction would proceed in a similar manner to the way it will proceed if you use [hot $\ce{KMnO4}$](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/oxidative-cleavage-alkenes-kmno4-o3/) as a reagent.

The reason I think that is because $\ce{HClO4}$ is practically similar to $\ce{KMnO4}$ structure and is an even stronger oxidizing agent ($\ce{Cl^{+7}}$ is much more unstable (and hence much more willing to oxidize) than $\ce{Mn^{+7}}$ ion) which should be able to imitate the behavior of hot $\ce{KMnO4}$ reagent (presuming that the greater oxidative strength compensates the level of reactivity  $\ce{KMnO4}$ shows at a higher temperature)

If the similarity is established then the reaction would proceed in this manner giving the products matching your answer:-

[image]

regarding the formation of aromatic cyclopropenium ion, I think cleavage of alkene relieves the angle strain which provides a higher stability than aromaticity.

**N.B.** :- Here I have presumed that $\ce{HClO4}$ can behave similar to hot $\ce{KMnO4}$ however I was unable to find a source for that.

Comment: Here is the source https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/131374/106370

Comment: @Rishi it is for $\ce{HIO4}$ and it doesn't suggest that $\ce{HIO4}$ can do oxidative cleavage of alkenes.